# How to perform sorting, filtering and page navigation in facelets using <h:dataTable> tag?

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, facelets

I am using JSF2.0 and facelets. How to perform sorting, filtering and page navigation in facelets using jsf dataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a component library like [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/), which has a dataTable with support for [sorting](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSorting.jsf) and [filtering](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf).

Comment: Thanks. How to increase the width of datatable in PrimeFaces?

Comment: The PrimeFaces dataTable has style and styleClass attributes, just like the JSF dataTable.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to do it reading BalusC articles

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html

I believe this will works fine with JSF2, maybe with some modifications.

Or you can use PrimeFaces as Mark said or [RichFaces](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333andJSF20)..